# Where can I ask a question regarding the policies and their applications of public school education on evolutionary biology in the USA?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

In the USA and/or California. I initially asked this question on the biology SE, you can see [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/82263/how-is-the-theory-of-evolution-taught-in-public-school-education#)

> How is evolution taught in public school education i.e. K-12? Those of you who work with students in grades 6-12, or know of someone, how is evolution taught? Is there still a negative view towards evolution usually misunderstandings about it? What about the creation vs evolution debate? Also, if there are any links you may know of that provide such information would be very helpful.

Comment: This is too broad for any Stack Exchange site. It is more like a poll ("share your experience") than an actual question. It is also highly localized.

Comment: @CodyGray Not quite. I would except some evidence that would back up their claim e.g. their curriculum or district standards. Also, I included "links" as in sources from books or articles that have done studies regarding this topic. The USA is high localized?

Comment: There are *massive* differences in different states of the USA.

Comment: @CodyGray - You under sold your statement.  There are massive differences between individual schools within individual districts within different states of the USA :-)

Comment: Don't forget about the differences between individual teachers, @Ramhound.